# Regular Expression (REGEX) Find & Replace in Visual Studio

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find and replace in my code the next line while N is number:

`[WorkItem(N)]`

and replace all the matching lines with:

`[Trait("Work Item","N")]`

for example:

Find: `[WorkItem(123)]`  Replace with: `[Trait("Work Item","123")]`

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: what is VS? This can be done using backreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern in find section: `(Work)(Item)\((\d+)\)` and this for replace section: `Trait("$1 $2", "$3")`

[image]